# Disjoint Union of First Countable Spaces

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, first-countable

This question concerns part $d)$ of proposition 3.42 of Lee's book on topological manifolds.

> Let $ \left( X_{\alpha} \right)_{\alpha \in A} $ be an (arbitrary) indexed family of topological spaces. If each $X_{\alpha}$ is first countable, then $X = \coprod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$ is first countable.

---

My attempt:

For each $\alpha$, let $\mathcal{B}_{p_{\alpha}}$ be a neighborhood basis for $p_{\alpha} \in X_{\alpha}$ and take $\mathcal{B}_{p} = \coprod_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{B}_{p_{\alpha}}$. It's not hard to show that for any $U \subseteq X$ neighborhood of $p$, there is a $B \in \mathcal{B}_p$ with $B \subseteq U$.

Consider now the bijection $\psi_{\alpha} : \mathcal{B}_{p_{\alpha}} \to \mathbb{N}$ and the canonical injection $\iota_{\alpha} : \mathcal{B}_{p_{\alpha}} \to \mathcal{B}_p$ given by $B_i \mapsto \left(B_i, \alpha\right)$. Take $g = \iota_{\alpha} \circ \psi^{-1}_{\alpha} : \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{B}_p$. It is clear that $g$ is injective.

The goal now would be to construct or show the existence of an injection from $\mathcal{B}_p $ to $\mathbb{N}$ and then proceed to use Schroeder-Bernstein's theorem. If there is an injection $\phi_{\alpha}: \mathcal{B}_p \to \mathcal{B}_{p_{\alpha}}$, then $f = \psi_{\alpha} \circ \phi_{\alpha}: \mathcal{B}_p \to \mathbb{N}$ would be the desired injection. However, the map $\iota^{-1}_{\alpha}$ is not injective. Is there such an injection? Is this approach salvageable? If not, which approach would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in that you haven't defined $\mathcal{B}_p$. I am also concerned that you think the disjoint union space is like the product space, in that $p\in X$ is really equal to a family $(p_\alpha\in X_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$. This is not so.

You don't even really need to worry about setting up injections, bijections (but you can if you want to).

> It's not hard to show that for any $U\subseteq X$ a
> neighbourhood of $p$, there is a $B\in\mathcal{B}_{p_\alpha}$ with $B\subseteq U$.

With this remark alone, you are essentially done. Any $p\in X$ is necessarily a $p\in X_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$. **Fixing** this $\alpha$, there is a countable local base $\mathcal{B}_{p_\alpha}$ for the topology of $X_\alpha$ at $p$. You recognise that every element of this basis remains open in $X$, and you also recognise that any neighbourhood of $p\in X$ contains an element of this basis. By very definition, $\mathcal{B}_{p_\alpha}$ is a countable basis for the topology of $X$ at $p$. As $p$ is arbitrary, you are done.

Comment: I forgot to define $\mathcal{B}_p$, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Nikolawn You still seem to be labouring under the misapprehension that elements $p$ of $X$ have coordinates $p_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$. No bijection can exist between your $\mathcal{B}_p$ and any individual $\mathcal{B}_{p_\alpha}$ when the index set is uncountable (and everything is nonempty).

Comment: Using $\coprod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} \times \{\alpha\}$. Wouldn't a point $p \in \coprod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}$ be of the form $p = \left( (p_{\alpha_1}, \alpha_1), \cdots, (p_{\alpha_n}, \alpha_n), \cdots \right)$?

Comment: @Nikolawn No. For example, $\{1,2\}\sqcup\{3,4\}$ is identifiably $\{1,2,3,4\}$. $(2,3)$ is not an element, e.g. . $p$ is in the union you describe iff. $p$ is in *one* of the sets that form the union (they are all disjoint, note) ie $p=(x_\alpha,\alpha)$ for exactly *one* $\alpha$.

Comment: I see now, forgive me for my misunderstanding. Thank you for clarifying it for me!

Comment: @Nikolawn No problem! Mixing up coproducts with products is easily done